# How to change editor colors in VuGen (LoadRunner Script Editor)

Tags: loadrunner

Is it possible to change the text/syntax-highlight colors in VuGen? If so where and how?

EDIT: My LoadRunner version is v11 + all patches to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the color.dat file in the {LoadRunner Home Directory}\dat subdirectory.   I have had to make changes in the past for red/green colorblind folks and this is the file to make the modifications global in.

Be sure and back up the original version before you start making changes.

Comment: I can't find the file? It does not exist with that name in that directory!! (My LR Version is 11 + all pathces)

Comment: This has been constant from 7.x-9.x of LoadRunner.   I would search your LR home and subdirectory for a file with the pattern of color*.*.   HP may have moved this to an ini file or a different directory with 11.x

Comment: Strange enough I found the file on my other installation (Win7 x64, LR v11), but the WinXP x86 LR v11 installation does not have that file. I guess I need to check my installation on the XP machine ..

Comment: I've now found both files on both machines, but ALAS NOTHING HAPPENS when I change the colors!! Changing the existing definitions makes no colors change - nothing - nowhere! (Even booted the machines just to see if pre-compilation of the file happens at some stage)

Comment: Odd...very odd....  Changing the standard colors works for me with LR 9.x.    If it doesn't work in your environment I would be inclined to cite it as a defect to HP.   For one of your environments, VUGEN on Win64, you will reach a limitation of support

Comment: I tried both the WinXP and Win7 installations, same thing on both.. Perhaps this color.dat file is no longer relevant in ver 11? I shall raise the question with HP when next we meet, as this is not too imporant, just nice to have!